# VS 2005 Toolbox kind of control .NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm looking for a control that the Visual Studio "Toolbox" menu uses. It can be docked and can retract (pin).

Would you know where I can find a control or COM I could use which would look like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite) by Weifen Luo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use a normal form (set the form type to Tool) and use the docking property to dock to to the left or right. You can set the width if you like and use the resize event to stop the user from making it too big or small.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what language you want to use. For C++, use the Feature Pack.